# How to find firmlinks

Tags: macos-catalina, apfs

macOS Catalina introduces "firmlinks" to the APFS filesystem. Is there a way via a CLI tool to determine whether /Users is a firmlink and where it is firmlinking to? I'm looking for something similar to the `readlink` command for symlinks.

Answer (score 3):

A list of the system firmlinks can be found in the file /usr/share/firmlinks.

On macOS Catalina version 10.15.1, the contents of the firmlinks file appear as follows:

```
/AppleInternal  AppleInternal
/Applications   Applications
/Library        Library
/System/Library/Caches  System/Library/Caches
/System/Library/Assets  System/Library/Assets
/System/Library/PreinstalledAssets      System/Library/PreinstalledAssets
/System/Library/AssetsV2        System/Library/AssetsV2
/System/Library/PreinstalledAssetsV2    System/Library/PreinstalledAssetsV2
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library  System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library
/System/Library/Speech  System/Library/Speech
/Users  Users
/Volumes        Volumes
/cores  cores
/opt    opt
/private        private
/usr/local      usr/local
/usr/libexec/cups       usr/libexec/cups
/usr/share/snmp usr/share/snmp
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm also looking for this. In the meantime, I've resorted to using comparing the results of `pwd -P` (show physical path of process working directory) with that of `df .`, e.g.:

```
# cd /Users ; pwd -P ; df .; cd - >/dev/null
/Users
Filesystem   512-blocks       Used Available Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1 1953595632 1384119832 545065168    72% 1287392 9766690768    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
```

(The final `cd -` switches back to the original directory, and prints out the directory path, hence the redirection to `/dev/null`.)

Note how the output of `pwd -P` says `/Users`, while `df` says it is mounted on `/System/Volumes/Data`.

Answer (score 0):

*Note:* the answer below is a partial *non-answer*, because there is something wrong with the firmlink flag in macOS or in `stat`. (An explanation or solution would be most welcome.)

XNU's **[/sys/stat.h](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/main/bsd/sys/stat.h#L512)** has a **flag** for firmlinks (**`SF_FIRMLINK`**). Normally you would check for a flag by reading the decimal output of all user flags with the **stat** command, converting it to hexadecimal, and testing bitwise against the hexadecimal value of the respective flag.

Example for `Applications`, testing for `SF_NOUNLINK` (`0x00100000`):

```
filepath="/Applications"
flag_hex="0x00100000"
st_flags=$(printf '0x%x' $(stat -f %f "$filepath"))
[[ $((( $(echo "$st_flags") & $flag_hex ))) -eq 0 ]] && echo "Flag $flag_hex is *not* set" || echo "Flag $flag_hex is set"
```

This will print that `Flag 0x00100000 is set`.

Conversely, testing for an unset flag, e.g. `UF_HIDDEN` (`0x00008000`), would result in a negative, because in our case `/Applications` is not a hidden file.

```
filepath="/Applications"
flag_hex="0x00008000"
st_flags=$(printf '0x%x' $(stat -f %f "$filepath"))
[[ $((( $(echo "$st_flags") & $flag_hex ))) -eq 0 ]] && echo "Flag $flag_hex is *not* set" || echo "Flag $flag_hex is set"
```

The problems, however, begin with firmlinks. Let's test for the firmlink flag of `/Applications`:

```
filepath="/Applications"
flag_hex="0x00800000"
st_flags=$(printf '0x%x' $(stat -f %f "$filepath"))
[[ $((( $(echo "$st_flags") & $flag_hex ))) -eq 0 ]] && echo "Flag $flag_hex is *not* set" || echo "Flag $flag_hex is set"
```

This should output `Flag 0x00800000 is set`, but it does not. Instead it tells us that the `SF_FIRMLINK` flag is *not* set, even though `/Applications` is objectively a firmlink.

When you just look at the variable `$st_flags`…

```
filepath="/Applications"
st_flags=$(printf '0x%x' $(stat -f %f "$filepath"))
echo "$st_flags"
```

…then the output is just `0x100000` (`SF_NOUNLINK` only), but not `0x900000` (combined `SF_NOUNLINK` and `SF_FIRMLINK`).

This means that either macOS is not writing this flag *at all*, even though it's defined in `/sys/stat.h`, or (more likely) Apple have deliberately kept this flag out of `stat`, `lstat` etc.

Either way, for the command-line it currently seems that we can only base a solution on **[Hambly's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1503273/628346)**, unless someone knows or can create a tool that is somehow able to read these file flags without using stat/lstat. You would probably have to apply methods like **getattrlist()**, which according to its man page is like a "seriously enhanced version of stat(2)".

For the command-line you probably should also take **synthetic firmlinks** into account. So a quick solution (firmlink yes|no) would look e.g. like this:

```
firmlinks=$(awk '{print $1}' < /usr/share/firmlinks)
synthetics=$(grep -v -e "^$" -e "\#" < "/etc/synthetic.conf" | awk '{print "/"$1}')
firmlinks=$(echo -e "$firmlinks\n$synthetics" | grep -v "^$" | sort)
for filepath in "$@"
do
    filepath=$(echo "$filepath" | sed 's-/$--')
    echo "$firmlinks" | grep -q "^$filepath$" &>/dev/null && echo "Firmlink: $filepath"
done
```

The following would be a proper solution to also print the actual link information e.g. `Firmlink: /Users -> Users`

```
firmlinks=$(cat /usr/share/firmlinks 2>/dev/null)
synthetics=$(grep -v -e "^$" -e "\#" < "/etc/synthetic.conf" 2>/dev/null | sed 's-^-/-g')
firmlinks=$(echo -e "$firmlinks\n$synthetics" | grep -v "^$" | sort)
for filepath in "$@"
do
    filepath=$(echo "$filepath/" | sed 's-/*$--')
    firmlink_raw=$(echo "$firmlinks" | grep "^$filepath\t")
    if [[ $firmlink_raw ]] ; then
        firmlink1=$(echo "$firmlink_raw" | awk -F\t '{print $1}')
        firmlink2=$(echo "$firmlink_raw" | awk -F\t '{print $2}')
        echo "Firmlink: $firmlink1 -> $firmlink2"
    fi
done
```